# Devise New User Registration Not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a fairly simple login form in my Rails 5.2 app with Devise, but when I hit "create my account" it's just refreshing the form and not saving.

My devise `User` model looks like this:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "membership", default: "Free"
    t.boolean "contributor", default: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

And my custom `registrations_controller.rb` looks like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :email,

      :membership,
      :contributor,
      :admin,

      :password,
      :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :email,

      :membership,
      :contributor,
      :admin,

      :password,
      :password_confirmation,
      :current_password)
  end
end
```

I added it to my routes with `devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }`.

I customized the `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` like this and it renders properly:

```
<main class="my-5 py-5">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="card">

      <div class="card-header text-center">
        Create an Account
      </div> <!-- card header -->

      <div class="card-body px-lg-5">

        <!-- Form -->
        <form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="#!">

        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>
           <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages" %>


          <div class="form-inputs">
            <h5 class="card-title pb-0 mb-0">Basic Information</h5>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="md-form mb-1">
                  <%= f.text_field :first_name,
                            class: "form-control",
                            id: "materialFormFirstName",
                            required: true,
                            label: false,
                            autofocus: true,
                            input_html: { autocomplete: "first_name" }%>
                  <label for="materialFormFirstName">First Name</label>
                </div> <!-- md-form -->
              </div> <!-- col -->

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="md-form mb-1">
                  <%= f.text_field :last_name,
                            class: "form-control",
                            id: "materialFormLastName",
                            required: true,
                            input_html: { autocomplete: "last_name" }%>
                  <label for="materialFormLastName">Last Name</label>
                </div> <!-- md-form -->
              </div> <!-- col -->

            </div> <!-- row -->

            <div class="md-form mb-1">
              <%= f.text_field :email,
                        class: "form-control",
                        id: "materialFormEmail",
                        required: true,
                        input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
              <label for="materialFormEmail">Email Address</label>
            </div> <!-- md-form -->

            <h5 class="card-title pb-0 pt-4 mb-0">Create a Password</h5>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="md-form mb-1">
                  <%= f.password_field :password,
                        class: "form-control",
                        required: true,
                        hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                        input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
                  <label for="materialFormFirstName">Password</label>
                </div> <!-- md-form -->
              </div> <!-- col -->

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="md-form mb-1">
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,
                        class: "form-control",
                        required: true,
                        input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
                  <label for="materialFormLastName">Confirm Password</label>
                </div> <!-- md-form -->
              </div> <!-- col -->

            </div> <!-- row -->
          </div> <!-- form inputs -->

          <div class="form-actions text-center mt-4">
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create My Account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <br><%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        </form>

      </div> <!-- card-body -->
    </div> <!-- card -->

  </div> <!-- container -->
</main>
```

Unfortunately, when I hit the "Create My Account" button, it just clears the form without saving the user.  My rails server log looks like this when it happens:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=eXNJIF0BC%2F7Ocwbf5C0ybrCrKS1oPEaHYCAogMtNAEszFUqw5G7J7TdhJOUSvmO6IesUrWL4rxKzjePjUyM5Hg%3D%3D&user%5Bfirst_name%5D=Liz&user%5Blast_name%5D=Bayardelle&user%5Bemail%5D=lizbayardelle%40gmail.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=[FILTERED]&commit=Create+My+Account" for ::1 at 2019-10-01 10:05:46 -0700
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eXNJIF0BC/7Ocwbf5C0ybrCrKS1oPEaHYCAogMtNAEszFUqw5G7J7TdhJOUSvmO6IesUrWL4rxKzjePjUyM5Hg==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Liz", "last_name"=>"Bayardelle", "email"=>"lizbayardelle@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create My Account"}
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidenav.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_notifications.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 396ms (Views: 394.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Can anyone see what's going on here?  I've looked at a bunch of SO posts on trying to get errors to show, but I can't get it to throw up any errors or give me any indication of what's going wrong.

Comment: The second line shows the issue I think - you're hitting the new action of your registrations controller instead of the create action

Comment: You need to modify the `<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>` line

Comment: @Mark What do I change it to?  This is the out of the box form generated by Devise.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure - I'd assumed you'd made that form yourself. Did you run `rails devise generate:views`?

Comment: It's definitely hitting the wrong controller action - the new action is the one that presents the form which is why it looks like it's clearing your input

Comment: @Mark, yes I ran `rails devise generate:views`, which is why it's so confusing that this is wonky.

Comment: @Mark I figured it out!  There was an extra form wrapping the devise form, so I guess it was submitting to the wrong one.  When I took that out it worked.

Comment: Glad you got there :)